net standard version to share between Xamarin Forms and MAUI
I have this new project on MAUI but I still need to support an old XF application, in order to reuse code Id like to share this code with a library (netstandard2.1) it works fine on MAUI side, when I tried to install the generated nuget package, it says:

NU1202: Package MyProject.Shared 1.0.0 is not compatible with netstandard2.1 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.1). Package MyProjectShared 1.0.0 supports: net8.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v8.0)

what I'm doing wrong?
MyProject.Shared.csproj
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.1</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>

    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Text.Json" Version="8.0.5" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>

